# update functionality in a nodejs/express and mongodb

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, crud, middleware

I am total beginner and I am trying to add an update functionality to my application. I am using a separate routes and controllers files that works with ejs templates

controller functions for the update task :

```
    function edit(req,res){
    Activity.findById(req.params.id, function(err, activity){
        // console.log(req.body)
            res.render('activities/edit',{activity} )
        
    })
}




function update(req, res){
    Activity.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, function(err, activity){
        console.log(req.params.id)

        // Activity.save(function(err){
        //     // if(true){
                
        //     // }
        //     // activity.title === req.body;
        //     console.log(input.value)

        // })
    })
    
            res.redirect('activities/show', { activity })

}
```

my form ˚

and my routes

```
`router.get('/:id/edit', activitiesCtrl.edit)

router.put('/:id',activitiesCtrl.update )
`
```

I am guessing what I got wrong has to do the form routes and the update controller function

this is my github for the whole project https://github.com/moeabraham/Activity-Tracker-Project
I am hoping to get pointers to what I am missing

Comment: What doesn't work?

Comment: it works now, main issue was with the redirect to the show view, apparently the show page was gonna get rendered but it doesn't have an id so that's why it was failing.

Comment: amazingly enough I am now working on the delete functionality and I am getting the same issue

Comment: The redirect call should be inside the Activity.findByIdAndUpdate

Comment: I am having a very similar issue with the delete functionality, do you mind taking a look at it ?
 function newDelete(req,res){
    console.log(req.params.id)
    Activity.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id, function(err, activity){
       
        res.redirect('/activities/index')

    })

}
router.delete('/activities/:id', activitiesCtrl.delete)
       <form action="/activities/<%= activity._id %>?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
        <input type="submit" value="delete">

       </form>